# DocuSign Connect Signing Complete Request URL?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

In DocuSign connect, I've configured it such that when a user has completed signing the documents that were emailed to them, DocuSign will send an HTTP POST request that includes the signed documents to an endpoint on an app on our servers that I've specified.

For the purpose of managing whitelists and firewalls, members of my team are asking what URL the request is going to come from. I haven't found a straightforward answer in the documentation. What URL does the request come from?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

The URL cannot be fixed and more URLs can be added in the future.
If you can use wildcards for something like *.docusign.net *.docusign.com then you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can whitelist specific DocuSign IP ranges defined for any of our sites. See the list on this [page](https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature)